# Public usage of Facebook in my android app for a community without releasing it on playstore

Tags: android, facebook, release

I have to release my android app for a closed group of people in a community. My app has Facebook integrated in it. I don't want to release it on Google play store. Facebook is asking for app icon, snapshots, policy url which i don't have. How to enable public usage of Facebook through my app. 
Please suggest.

Comment: have you generated the key,hash key etc

Answer (score 0):

go to the page in https://developers.facebook.com site go to your app,it will show your app ID and secret key,put youremail below and go to the next part you will see access for public by default it will be no change it yes 
i hope it will help

Comment: Make sure to click on save changes option :-D

Comment: I am getting the following message in the logcat.. “Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token”

Comment: Are you following the example given in  https://developers.facebook.com or something other,if your are following some other method then you should give app id in strings.xml which is in value folder in resources

Comment: and set permission regarding app id in manifest by using it in meta data